# Kähler forms on open manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

If an open smooth manifold admits a complex structure does it admit a complex structure with a compatible Kähler form?

Comment: No. Take a non-Kähler complex compact surface $S$, and $X=S\times \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @abx I don't understand your comment.

Comment: $X$ does not admit any Kähler metric, because it would induce a  Kähler metric on $S$.

Comment: @abx Indeed with respect to the product complex structure. Can there be a different one?

Comment: No. $S$ is a closed subvariety of $X$.

Comment: @abx Not necessarily if you take a different complex structure on the underlying smooth manifold of $X$ (which is what the question considering).

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. Indeed I misread the question.